# Three variable diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the following type of general 3-variable diophantine equation:
$$axyz + bxy + cxz + dyz + ex + fy +gz + h=0$$

(The variables are $x$, $y$ and $z$).

I know how to solve the less complicated 2-variable variant:
$$ axy + bx + cy + d =0 $$
After multiplying by $a$, the equation becomes $a^2xy + abx + acy + ad = 0$. From that point, we can complete the square and write $(ax+c)(ay+b)=bc-ad$.

The term on the right-hand side can be factored, and then matched against the left-hand side to obtain solutions.

I can't really see how to elegantly generalize this to the 3-variable case.

I tried multiplying by $a^2$ and factoring into $(ax+d)(ay+c)(az+b)$, but the latter's expansion gives $a^3xyz + a^2bxy + a^2cxz + a^2dyz + abcx + abdy + acdz + bcd$, while the original equation multiplied by $a^2$ is $a^3xyz + a^2bxy + a^2cxz + a^2dyz + a^2ex + a^2fy + a^2gz + a^2h = 0$.

Doing it that way looks like it might not work if $a^2e \ne abc$ for example.

Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: you should probably start with $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3 x y z.$ There are some differences, the quadratic form in yours is automatically indefinite. Still,...

Comment: Equation. 

$$axyz+bxy+cxz+dyz+ex+fy+gz+h=0$$

Write it differently.

$$(az+b)xy+(cz+e)x+(dz+f)y+(gz+h)=0$$

You know how to solve this equation.